# GPS stays activated after finish()

Tags: android, gps, listener, locationmanager, locationlistener

from an Activity (UI) I call a class to get my location.
At onPause in the activity I try to stop the Listeners, but the GPS icon in the status bar keeps blinking, this is the case on more devices (I read that it´s a HTC issue).

Can anybody tell me how I can fix this issue?

```
The GPS location class:

public GPSLocation (Context context) {
            myContext = context;

            LocatieManager=(LocationManager)myContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        }   

public void StopLocationListeners(){
     // LocationManager LocatieManager=(LocationManager)myContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
      LocatieManager.removeUpdates(netwerklistener);
      LocatieManager.removeUpdates(gpslistener);    
      LocatieManager.removeGpsStatusListener(gpsStatusListener);
}
```

From the UI activity, I call `mGPSLocation.StopLocationListeners();` in the onPause method, but this doesn´t work. Anybody can help me out and give a hint why this is not possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are closing GPS from public methods. but how can you be so sure that, the object which is currently running is getting close ?  what I mean to say is you might have more than one object of your location class. you need to use static for such purpose, so that while closing GPS it will close the particular one only.

Comment: I have the feeling this is the case. Not all running objects are closed. But should I make the class static? Because that is not permitted.

Comment: no, you can make your methods and variable to static. that will be fine

Comment: Thanks, I had also a mylocation overlay non static, but it works now! Great.

Answer (score 0):

after calling this

```
mGPSLocation.StopLocationListeners();
```

You can stop the LocationListener by making its object to null.. put this line

```
LocatieManager=null
```

in StopLocationListeners() Method..

Comment: Hi raju, thanks, only thing is that I get a Nullpointer Exception, since something is still running on the background.

Comment: you have put thie line "LocatieManager=null" after these three lines LocatieManager.removeUpdates(netwerklistener);
      LocatieManager.removeUpdates(gpslistener);    
      LocatieManager.removeGpsStatusListener(gpsStatusListener);.. right?

Comment: Yes, but there is another object running I think. It gives a nullpointer where it calls the LocatieManager, but it shouldn´t call the LocatieManager anymore, since the app is closed. I keep looking..